# function 'parent_theme_locations' not found or invalid function name

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am creating the child theme of twentythirteen. It works fine in localhost without any error but when I put live on the server I got the following error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'parent_theme_locations' not found or invalid
>   function name in
>   /home/nonaitpub/public_html/subedi/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on
>   line 496

Comment: Please post the full  error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had called function 'parent_theme_locations' somewhere in your functions.php file.Like `add_action('after_setup_theme','parent_theme_locations',20);`